Can a Grassmann Algebra turn into a Banach Algebra by some appropriate norm?
As we know a (finite) Grassmann Algebra $\Lambda_q$ is an algebra generated by $\{x_1,...x_q\}$ with the relation $x_ix_j+x_jx_i=0$, and hence a $2^q$-dimension vector space spanned by words of $x_1,...x_n$ of lenth no more than $q$. Also we know every finite-dimension vector space can be equipped with a unique (under equivalence) norm, so my question is :
Can we choose a norm such that multiplication of $\Lambda_q$ satisfy the Banach algebra condition $||ab||\leq||a||·||b||$? It seems that the standard one ($\sqrt{\sum a_i^2}$ where $a_i$ is the coefficient on basis) does not work:
take $q=2$ and we let $a=a_1+a_2\xi+a_3\eta+a_4\xi\eta$ together with $b=b_1+b_2\xi+b_3\eta+b_4\xi\eta$, then$||ab||$ have strictly more terms containing $a_1$ than $||a||·||b||$, say $a_1a_2b_1b_2$. So there cannot hold an inequality.
but this question should be so general that are there some well-known result I missed out or so?

The $\ell^1$ norm on words works.

@DavidGao oh OF COURSE you are right

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

Thanks to David Gao. We take $l^1$ norm on the coefficients of words and we get a well defined Banach algebra, since the multiplication of every two words only get one new word, or just vanish of course.
